# Pure (sub)module (in $M$)

Tags: modules, systems-of-equations, free-modules

What is the difference between a **pure module $P$** and a **pure module $P$ in a module $M$** ? I have a slight intuition though, what is the relationship between purity and solvability of equations.

Comment: As far as I know, only pure submodules have been defined.

Comment: @Bernard What if we define a **pure** $P$ without ambient module $M$ if all the (existential) positive primitive formulas are solvable in it ? What notion do we get ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what a primitive formula is. Are we speaking of the same concept (related to tensor product)?

Answer (score 0):

As Bernard says, there is no such thing as a pure module because it is a property of submodules.

In response to the second part of your question, consider the two different definitions of purity, the first using model theoretic notions which we will call pp-pure.

> **Definition** Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ is a left $R$-module. If $L$ is a submodule
>   of $M$, then the embedding $L\to M$ is *pure* if for every pp-formula
>   $\phi$ of length $n$, one has $$\phi(L)=L^{n}\cap\phi(M)$$
>   Here $\phi(M)=\{m\in M^{n}:M\models\phi(m)\}$.

This condition states that the inclusion preserves and reflects solutions to pp-formulae.

Now consider the following algebraic definition, which we will call $\otimes$-pure:

> **Definition** If $R$ is a ring and $M$ is a left $R$-module, then a submodule
>   $L\subseteq M$ is *pure* if for every right $R$-module $T$ the
>   sequence $$0\to T\otimes_{R}L\to T\otimes_{R}M$$ is exact.

So here is the relationship between the two:

> **Proposition** pp-purity and $\otimes$-purity are the same

I won't give a proof here, but one can be found in $\S 2.4$ of [these](https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/mike.prest/IsfahanSchoolRepAlg.pdf) notes by Mike Prest.

To talk about solutions of equations, we need pure injective.

> **Definition** An $R$-module $M$ is *pure injective* if and only if every system of equations with parameters in $M$ that is finitely solvable in $M$ is solvable in $M$.

There is also an algebraic definition of pure-injectivity, which is being injective over pure submodules.

Now, given any $R$-module $M$, there is a pure injective module $PI(M)$ and pure embedding $M\to PI(M)$ that is the 'smallest' pure injective module containing $M$ purely, called the *pure injective envelope* of $M$. Because $M\to PI(M)$ is a pure embedding, it reflects solutions to pp-formulae, all of which have solutions in $PI(M)$ (provided they're finitely solvable) as it is pure injective.

Obviously, if $M$ is pure-injective to begin with it is its own pure-injective hull and all systems of equations equations that are finitely solvable have solutions in it. As an example, any injective module is pure-injective, as is any finitely generated module over a complete local ring. Obviously there are many more.

An extensive description of purity and its role in the model theory of modules can be found in Mike Prest's book *[Purity, Spectra and Localisation](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/purity-spectra-and-localisation?format=HB&isbn=9780521873086)*.